# Deletion Method of Circular Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

This is the deletion method of a circular doubly linked list.

```
    // Deletion of node from CDLL
    void deleteNode(int location) {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("CDLL doesn't exist!");
            return;
        } else if (location == 0) {
            if (size == 1) {
                head.next = null;
                head.prev = null;
                head = null;
                tail = null;
                size--;
                return;
            } else {
                head = head.next;
                head.prev = tail;
                tail.next = head;
                size--;
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is ->
-This part of the code deletes the first node of the linked list.
-In the "else if" condition (where "location == 0")
-Inside it where "if (size == 1)"
-This means that we are deleting the first node when there is only one node in the linkedlist.
-If we only write this much ->

```
if (size == 1) {
                head = null;
                tail = null;
                size--;
                return;
                }
```

-Will the first node still be collected by the garbage collector?
-I think it should be collected by the garbage collector because there is nothing pointing to that one node anymore, the head and tail are null.
-Please answer.

Comment: So, it will not be collected by garbage collector, if there are circular reference? (Just to be sure I understant.)

Comment: WRONG, I wrote "will **NOT avoid** it being collected" - garbage collectors are pretty smart

Comment: I didn't undertand your latest comment but Thanks for your answer now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be garbage collected even when the line

```java
head.next = null;
head.prev = null;
```

are omitted.

Whether the attributes `next` and `prev` are different from `null` depends from the definition for your CDLL, they could be also set to `head`. Refer to the method that adds new entries to answer this question if you are interested.

But no matter which values the two attributes have, it does not matter for the garbage collector.

Comment: @AbinashDash – an upvote or an acceptance would be nice …

Comment: I didn't had enough reputations at that time, so I didn't upvoted. But now I have so I upvoted. Thanks again.